# JQuery send post request after submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Friends this is my code to form submit and then send post link but form submit success then after not send post link.

```
document.getElementById("pitch_image_path_form").submit(function(e){

$.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'},function(result){
                    $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

this is my code form is submit but post request is not send.

Comment: Any console errors? Can we see the form?

Comment: no not show any console error.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using that live() and die() work?

Comment: i used jQuery version is 1.7.2

Comment: @epascarello sorry dear but i can't get answer please help.

Comment: @renishkhunt You should consider asking question in a better way so. It's not clearer here than in your previous question. "**that code is not working**", for instance, is more a cry for help than a clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dear renishkhunt please try this code. this is help fully for me.

```
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").ajaxSubmit({ success: function(){ 
            $.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'},function(result){
                    $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result);
                });
     } });
```

please check this link this is tutorial.

```
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
```

Answer (score 1):

`.submit()` is a jQuery function, so you need to wrap your `$("#pitch_image_path_form")[0]` in a jQuery wrapper, like so:

`$($("#pitch_image_path_form")[0]).submit(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

There is no submit() event in DOM, you are mixing DOM and jQuery

change

```
document.getElementById("pitch_image_path_form").submit
```

to

```
$("#pitch_image_path_form").submit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("pitch_image_path_form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post(
    "submit_investorform.php",
    {'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'}
    , function(result) { $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result); }
);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Because DOM does not support submit(), there is do submit() function in DOM. Same exact answer when you asked this the last time.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.submit()`, it posts the form with the specified action of the `<form>`.

You might want to stop the propagation, by using either `event.stopPropagation();`, `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` at the end of your function.

```
 $("#pitch_image_path_form").submit(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        event.preventDefault();

        //Your .post()

        return false;
    });
```

Plus, as epascarello pointed out, `.submit()` is a jQuery function.

If you want to use it, use it on the jQuery object by removing `[0]` before `submit()`, **as you're not supposed to have multiple elements with the same ID**.