# JQuery after submit form post link is not send?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends this is my code.

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").die('change').live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form")[0].submit(function(){
        $.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'},function(result){
            $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result);
        });
    });

    });
```

i try to form is submit then after the send post link but that code is not working.

the form is submit but post link is not send.
Thanks

Comment: You already asked the same question [JQuery send post request after submit form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565648/jquery-send-post-request-after-submit-form)